# How to get a transparent background for default tab controller, I tried to set the backgroundcolor to Colors.transparent, but it doesn't work fine

Tags: flutter, dart, transparent

Here is the code,

```
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Fresh Juice"),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(35),
          topRight: Radius.circular(35),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(35),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
        ),
        boxShadow: CustomTheme.cardshadow,
      ),
      child: const TabBar(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
        tabs: [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.person)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: const TabBarView(
      children: [
        HomeScreen(),
        ProfileScreen(),
        CheckoutScreen(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I was trying to get the canvas's background color transparent, as my dock is white, but when I scroll, it shows a blue indicator that makes it look like it is fit in a container with a white background.

I would like to completely hide the background, I want a floating dock. with a white background and the canvas that is visible, should become transparent when I scroll. looking for perfection*